# sharepoint designer pages in web application development

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

Is it possible to reuse the mockup UIs, created in sharepoint designer, in actual application development in later stages.

To be more clear, is it possible to use the aspx pages created in sharepoint designer in visual studio for the web application development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UI of sharepoint is standard ASP.NET master pages/aspx pages, so yes you could use them in visual studio, building a sharepoint component.

Adding them as a module element would be straight forward.

Adding them to a list definition, you might need to fix up GUID references and remove all the sharepoint designer meta tags.

Building a custom asp.net application, probably not, as you would not have access to the sharepoint host, binaries or web controls.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use aspx page in your web site. if you will not login in website and creates new aspx page then you have the basic components. Don't use the share point components if it is available.i.e. Web Parts, List View, etc